# Easiest way for testing the internal GPS

Tags: gps

What is the easiest way to verify that the internal GPS module of an android device works correctly (possibly before buying some expensive navigation software)?

Geotagging a foto?
Running some free diagnostic tool?

Please note that I'm referring to internal GPS, not the bluetooth ones or the A-GPS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by internal GPS you mean the postion fix using GPS satellites, you can use "GPS Status & Toolbox" app to get a fix and also know how long it took to get the fix.

Comment: sorry, don't know how I didn't notice you suggesting the same app. I've given you a +1

Answer (score 4):

I'd say fire up Google Maps and see if you are where it says you are.

Comment: Definitely. Open GMaps and press the push-pin icon to the right of the search box.

Comment: Careful, Android can very good at determining your location from WiFi signals, even without a working GPS.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the model, you can get into the GpsSetup2 with the code `*#*#1472365#*#*` (works at least with Android 2.1 on a samsung galaxy 5 device), and inside it you go to:

```
Commands -> Get position -> Start GPS
```

where the device will try to connect to the satellites nearby, and will tell your position.
First time I did it, it took more than six minutes to get it done.

Answer (score 2):

The (free) [GPS Status app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/gps-status-toolbox/com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) gives you all sorts of stats about your GPS, including time-to-first-lock, current accuracy, signal strengths, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not always sufficient to confirm that the Maps app shows your location.  You also need to ensure that your location is transmitted back to the server, otherwise real time navigation won't work.  Under "Location and Privacy" there should be a setting "Location" which lets you choose either "E911 Only" or "Location On" or something similar to that.  You need to have that set to Location On in order for real-time navigation to work.

In the custom ROM I last flashed, there's some kind of bug concerning GPS, and navigation doesn't work. In my settings I can't even find the option to toggle between E911 and "Location On". I really hate having to do this, because I like my current ROM for other reasons.   But I'm going to have to go back to HydroRom because I really want to have navigation working.

Answer (score 0):

[GpsIsUp](http://abelus.com/gpsisup) uses the GPS hardware exclusively and it has a handy user's guide